# Looping through till you receive correct validation input Powershell

Tags: powershell, loops, input, user-input, sqlcmd

I would like the code to keep looping through till it recieves the right validation input. If the user enters yes, the the script can continue to execute. if the user enters no, it will ask the user to check the output from the previous script. If the user enters anything other than no, I want program to let the user know it has to be a yes or no answer, but also loop back through and ask the question. What am I missing in my code to allow this?

```
$user_input = Read-Host "Does id look correct? [yes/no]"

if ($user_input -eq 'yes'){
    Write-Host "Running Pre- script..."

    $SQLServer3 = "ServerB" 
    $Database3 = 'master'


    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SQLServer3 -Database $Database3 -InputFile "C:\Users\Documents\Scripts\Restore.txt"
} 

    elseif ($user_input -eq 'no') {
     Write-Host "Check id"

    }
   else {

    Write-Host "Answer must be 'yes' or 'no'"

}
```

Comment: This is much easier using `PromptForChoice(..)` from PSHost.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon thanks, I used it and it works great

Answer (score 0):

Using [`PrompForChoice`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.host.pshostuserinterface.promptforchoice?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0) your script can look like this as it already ensures one of the *choices* has to be selected:

```
if($Host.UI.PromptForChoice($null, 'Does id look correct?', ('&Yes', '&No'), 0) -eq 0) {
    Write-Host 'Running Pre- script...'

    $invokeSqlcmdSplat = @{
        ServerInstance = 'ServerB'
        Database       = 'master'
        InputFile      = 'C:\Users\Documents\Scripts\Restore.txt'
    }
    Invoke-Sqlcmd @invokeSqlcmdSplat
}
else {
    Write-Host 'Check id'
}
```